# USA: Was suing for non-compete agreements, misappropriation of trade secrets, breach of contract, tortious inference, not a thing before 2008?

Tags: non-compete

I have 2 other examples, but they were recent, they were after 2008. Are there any notable earlier ones?

Comment: Text as Image is Bad. Please write the text out.

Comment: @Trish Too long by 5739 characters. Do you want me to post it as an answer? But the text in image isn't my question.

Comment: Uhm.... The text in that image is merely 1705 Characters?! you have 30k characters.

Comment: @Trish no, comments don't allow for 30k characters. I meant I was trying to paste it here.

Comment: You are meant to put it **into the question**

Comment: @Trish then I would be double posting a lot of text, which seems redundant.

Comment: No, you can jsut remove the superflous picture then. For a screenreader, there's just a heading, then the last line, and none of the examoples. You are getting downvotes for making a post that is very much excluding people that use small screens or screenreaders, and **also** violating the "No image in texts" Policy: https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/should-we-have-an-explicit-policy-against-images-of-text

Comment: @Trish I never understood the concept of taking offense to additional information when it doesn't slow down reading time.

Comment: it's **also** technically forbidden Stackwide to use images that depict text: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors

Comment: @Trish you probably don't remember me, but this is my 5th or 6th question I've asked here, and every single 1 of them were shut down. So I'm going to assume this thread will be shut down as well. Take offense to my image while it still lasts.

Comment: And I disagree. People in chemistry stackexchange use images with text all the time.

Comment: This is not chemistry SE. Here, Images with text are banned. See https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1479/should-we-have-an-explicit-policy-against-images-of-text

Comment: @Trish I'm aware, I was replying to your "Stackwide."

Answer (score 1):

Most of these examples involve California companies, a state which is famous for its weak enforcement of (and refusal to enforce) non-competition agreements (Twohig might be from Washington State which is similar). In contrast, such agreements are very strictly enforced in Massachusetts, in particular, and on the East Coast, generally.

Comment: Ah yes, some were in state court and some federal. I knew I should have better prepared this collage by specifying the jurisdiction.

Comment: @NealConroy Generally, even in federal court, these cases would be subject to diversity jurisdiction and subject to state substantive law.

Comment: so someone leaving a a Massachusetts company for a California company, can sue in Massachusestts court, and someone leaving a California company to a Massachusetts company, can still sue in Massachussetss? All of these are former-company suing newer-company, so.

Comment: @NealConroy Generally, the law of the former company's HQ would be the key issue.